# popup multiple div tag

Tags: jquery, ajax, popup

i am trying to get information(ajax) and display it inside a popup(jquery or equivalent) however my problem is i have multiple div tag in my page.

```
<div id="1"><a href="#">mouseover detail for id #1</a></div>
<div id="2"><a href="#">mouseover detail for id #2</a></div>
<div id="3"><a href="#">mouseover detail for id #3</a></div>
```

OR

```
<div><a href="get.php?id=1">mouseover detail for id #1</a></div>
<div><a href="get.php?id=2">mouseover detail for id #2</a></div>
<div><a href="get.php?id=3">mouseover detail for id #3</a></div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class for the divs to let you write generic code like..

```
<div class="someclass" data-id="1"><a href="#">mouseover detail for id #1</a></div>
<div class="someclass" data-id="2"><a href="#">mouseover detail for id #2</a></div>
<div class="someclass" data-id="3"><a href="#">mouseover detail for id #3</a></div>
```

And then write code like...

```
var SM=null;
$('.someclass').hover(function(){
    var data=$(this).attr('data-id');

    if(data==null) return;

    var url='get.php?'+data;

    $.get(url,function(response){
         // taken from simplemodal samples page.
         SM = new SimpleModal({"btn_ok":"Alert button"});
         SM.show({
              "title":"Title",
              "contents":response
         });
    },function(){
         // not sure about the close method.
         // probably SM.close() or SM.hide(). If you have worked on it, add it here.
         });
    });
```

Comment: thank you for your help. How can i open jquery popup OnMouseOver and what should i write inside of response?

Comment: Do you mean jQuery UI popup? If yes, then I will edit my answer now with updates.

Comment: yes, i want to popup returned information with style applied from get.php when mouse is over of <a> tag and hide it on mouse move from <a> tag